# Python requests: sending file via POST returns ConnectionError

Tags: python, rest, python-requests

I'm trying to use the Python requests library to send an android .apk file to a API service. I've successfully used requests and this file type to submit to another service but I keep getting a:

> ConnectionError(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='REDACTED', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /upload/app (Caused by : [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host)",),)

This is the code responsible:

```
url = "https://website"
files = {'file': open(app, 'rb')}
headers = {'user':'value', 'pass':'value'}
try:
    response = requests.post(url, files=files, headers=headers)
    jsonResponse = json.loads(response.text)
    if 'error' in jsonResponse:
        logger.error(jsonResponse['error'])
except Exception as e:
    logger.error("Exception when trying to upload app to host")
```

The response line is throwing the above mentioned exception. I've used these exact same parameters using the Chrome Postman extension to replicate the POST request and it works perfectly. I've used the exact same format of file to upload to another RESTful service as well. The only difference between this request and the one that works is that this one has custom headers attached in order to verify the POST. The API doesn't stipulate this as authentication in the sense of needing to be encoded and the examples both in HTTP and cURL define these values as headers or -H.

Any help would be most appreciated!

Comment: The only thing I can think for it working in a Chrome extension and not with requests is that the remote host looks for a valid user agent. Maybe they want to restrict submission with scripts.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me get closer to the answer. Now it looks like I'm missing the proper cert to connect so I'm trying to figure out to get that working.

Answer (score 0):

So this was indeed a certificates issue. In my case I was able to stay internal to my company and connect to another URL, but the requests library, which is quite amazing, has information on certs at: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/?highlight=certs
For all intents and purposes this is answered but perhaps it will be useful to someone in posterity.

Comment: Can you please explain this solution better? I don't know what "this was a certificates issue" means..

Comment: I am also facing similar issues. @JeffreyThe link you shared is no longer valid  (my bad luck). Can you please help me with this